# Android Invalidate() only single view

Tags: android, android-view

I have 2 views on `RelativeLayout`

I need to invoke(call) onDraw only single view

when I try `view1.invalidate();`  it also invoke(call) onDraw (view2 draw)

what to do?

thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution? Any of the responses were useful to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `view1` is  overlapping  with `view2` when you call `view1.invalidate();` it will re-draw every View that is overlapping with it .. so it will call `view2.onDraw();` and since you are using `RelativeLayout` view1 and view2 maybe overlapped each other .

Comment: 2 view draw need very big time and what to do? can I save canvas object and when view2 need to draw to give saved canvas?

Comment: does the 2 views need to be overlapped ?? if you don't know show me an image

Answer (score 1):

I met the same question.

Finally, I found that drawing cache is disabled in android 2.3. Because of no cache, each time the view will redraw itself even the other invalidated.

To make cache enable, use:

```
setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)
```

The question is too old, but google put it first when I searched. I think it is useful for others who get into here.