# Why is my layout completely redrawing when I invalidate one of it's views?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a complex frame layout containing several custom views.  The main view is a graph.

Overlaying the graph is a custom view which represents a cross hair pointer that the user can drag around the graph to read off detailed information about a particular data point.

The frame layout captures all touch events, calls "hit test" methods on each of it's child views to determine if the touch was on that view then dispatches the touch event to the appropriate view.

When the user touches the cross hair and drags it, I pass the touch event to the cross hair which it uses to update it's position and invalidate itself.

Everything is working except...

All views in the layout are redrawing when I invalidate any of these child views.  I know this as I have turned on "show screen updates" in developer options. At no point do I invalidate the containing FrameLayout - or at least, not knowingly.

Certainly, the Activity handling the layout does not invalidate it and I do not have any references to the parent in the child views.

I haven't posted code since a) I don't know if this might be normal behaviour, b) there's a lot of it! and c) if it's not normal behaviour, I don't know which part of the code is problematic.  Of course, I'm happy to give anything that might be requested.

My minimum API is 2.3.3 and my target is 4.0.  This happens on both of those versions so I suspect my code is the problem but where to start?

Any clues as to what might be going on?

Comment: You say `I suspect my code is the problem`, so why don't you post the code?

Comment: @tolgap Please see my comment about why I didn't post code.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way for `View` to draw "just itself", since it depends on it's parent (which provides it's clipped and translated `Canvas` via `dispatchDraw` method). Invalidation requires whole view tree to be invalidated - this is the answer that you're looking for :)

If you'll check out the source of `ViewGroup`, you'll find there two important methods: `dispatchDraw` (which responsible for dispatching draw event down to it's childs) and `drawChild` (which called by `dispatchDraw` and let's you specify how childs will be drawn). Note, that there is no check on which `View` starts invalidation, although there is a `RectF` that specifies invalidation region. As far as I understand - you need to make sure that your invalidating `View` (cross) doesn't takes the whole screen, so redrawn will be only that part that it actually takes.

Comment: Ah, that makes total sense.  The problem I've got is that the view must be the same size as it's parent since I draw a horizontal and vertical line the width and height of the graph which it overlays.  So, if I understand correctly, there is nothing I can do unless I split the cross into two views and set their size to the thickness of the line and position them with the x and ys.  That way, only the RectF which is actually invalidated with redraw? I'll play with this a little (I think I understand the cause now) and come back in a few hours.  Thanks!

Comment: @Simon don't forget about drawing cache. While redrawing, there is possibility that cache will be drawn to preserve resources. So, unless you have some performance issues, there is no need to worry about redrawing of whole view tree.

Comment: OK, good to know.  I don't actually have a performance issue, and I'm not doing premature optimisation - just that I noticed everything being redrawn and that looked ugly to me.  But, you're insight has helped me a lot.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If understand you right, the lines of the cross-hair view cover the whole screen, i.e. one vertical line from top to bottom and one horizontal from left to right.

Now if you change the center of the cross-hair and the other views would not be redrawn, your screen would soon be cluttered with old lines from previous cross-hair positions. You would not want this, so you can be glad that the other views redraw itself too.

If you want, you can specify a 'dirty' rectangle and  call [invalidate(Rect dirty)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28android.graphics.Rect%29), which would not redraw Views that are completely outside that rectangle. Though it's up to you in that case, not to change anything outside that rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
```

Enabling drawing cache for view will make view not be redrawn if view not changed

Take a look :  [Android Invalidate() only single view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120986/android-invalidate-only-single-view)

Answer (score 0):

May be my answer so simple, but I resolved this problem with help:

```
this.invalidate()
```

Run it for each canvas-view, and it will updating one by one (not all at once)