# onDraw being called in other custom views when calling invalidate

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I have two custom views that have the same methods and when I call `invalidate()` in one it calls the `onDraw` method in both. I tried several methods including `this.invalidate()` but it still calls it. The only way I can think of it working is adding a boolean to the other class to check it it was called for itself inside the `onDraw()`.

## Custom View 1

```
public void showPercentage(double percent, double out){
    cropx =  (int) percent;
    outof = (int) out;
    this.invalidate();
}
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if(cropx != 0){
    croppedBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawGraph2, 0, 0, (drawGraph2.getWidth()*cropx/100), drawGraph2.getHeight());
    canvas.drawBitmap(croppedBmp, 0, 0, new Paint());
    croppedBmp.recycle();
    System.gc();
    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
    }
}
```

## Custom View 2

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    //System.out.print to check if its being called
    System.out.println("hey");
    Bitmap croppedBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawGraph2);
    canvas.drawBitmap(croppedBmp, 0, 0, new Paint());
}
```

Comment: Do you extend one from another? For example you extend Custom View 2 from Custom View 1.

Comment: @CsehTamás Both extend View.

Comment: Can you post your test code?

Comment: Class 1: http://pastebin.com/rpJJPrHW
Class 2: http://pastebin.com/iNriz0Fr

Comment: Are these views inside a MultiPassLayout (RelativeLayout or LinearLayout with weights). Please give the view hierarchy how these views are placed in layout.

Comment: Yes. All are on top of each other in a relative layout. I don't have access to the code as I'm on my phone but will update you with the code ASAP.

Comment: I think that when you invalidate your view, the other one is refreshed too because of the behaviour of relative layout. When something changes it measures everything again since all the positions are relatives. It probably redraws just after.

Comment: k3v1n4ud3 Any way to fix that.

Comment: Maybe by enclosing each view in a separate layout.

Comment: Found an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17185143/why-is-my-layout-completely-redrawing-when-i-invalidate-one-of-its-views